# i am getting a horizontal scrollbar when i use this right panel animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

i get this annoying horizontal scrollbar when i hover my moose on the button top. When the panel slides in from right and mouseout it goes back

this is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/Ej5k8/9/

```
$(function () {
$("#panel-content").hide();$(function () {
$("#panel-content").hide();

$("#follow").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#panel-content").show();
    $("#panel-content").animate({
        width: '300px'
    }, 'fast');

});

$("#panel-content").mouseleave(function () {
    if (!$("#panel-content").is(':animated')) {
        $("#panel-content").show();
        $("#panel-content").animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

});

```
$("#follow").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#panel-content").show();
    $("#panel-content").animate({
        width: '300px'
    }, 'fast');

});

$("#panel-content").mouseleave(function () {
    if (!$("#panel-content").is(':animated')) {
        $("#panel-content").show();
        $("#panel-content").animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

});

i dont want to use overflow-x as it shows scrollbars for my iframes use

is there any other way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Applying `overflow-x: hidden;` to the body will remove the undesired scrollbar. Are you able to elaborate on why you do not want to use it?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem you can see here http://jsfiddle.net/Ej5k8/21/ it was my mistake of keeping the position absolute. I made it fixed....thanks